# Array index out of bounds on line 30 error

Tags: java

Can someone please help me.

public class BuggyQuilt {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[][] myBlock = { { 'x', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
                         { 'x', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
                         { 'x', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
                         { 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' } };
    char[][] myQuilt = new char[3 * myBlock.length][4 * myBlock[0].length];

   createQuilt(myQuilt, myBlock);

    displayPattern(myQuilt);
}

public static void displayPattern(char[][] myArray) {
    for (int r = 0; r < myArray.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < myArray[0].length; c++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[c][r]);
        }
    }
}

public static void createQuilt(char[][] quilt, char[][] block) {
    char[][] flippedBlock = createFlipped(block);

    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            if (((r + c) % 2) == 0) {
                placeBlock(quilt , block, c * block.length ,
                        r * block[4].length);
            } else {
                placeBlock(flippedBlock, quilt, r * block.length ,
                        c * block[0].length);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void placeBlock(char[][] quilt, char[][] block, int startRow,
        int startCol) {
    for (int r = 0; r < block.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= block[r].length; c++) {
            quilt[r + startRow][c + startCol] = block[r][c];
        }
    }
}

public static char[][] createFlipped(char[][] block) {
    int blockRows = block.length - 3;
    int blockCols = block.length - 1;
    char[][] flipped = new char[blockRows][blockCols];
    
    int flippedRow = blockRows - 1;
    
    for (int row = 0; row < blockRows; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < blockCols; col++)
            flipped[flippedRow][col] = block[row][col];
    }

    return flipped;
}
```

}

output:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
at BuggyQuilt.createQuilt(BuggyQuilt.java:30)
at BuggyQuilt.main(BuggyQuilt.java:1

Comment: What is the difference between your code, and [this code](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs302/labs/lab07/solution/BuggyQuilt.java)?

Answer (score -1):

There are only 4 lines in block. You use block[4] index is obviously out of bounds.

Comment: sos what should I do?

Comment: @NijonKnight, element 1 is at _index value_ 0.  Meaning, if you want to get the 4th element, you would use _3_.  _[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)_.